# Getting values by comparing keys in scala

Tags: scala, apache-kafka

I am new to scala and at  a very beginner level and trying to write  some code in it. I am working on scala application with kafka. I have following code.

```
  IncomintKey: String = ""
  val record = consumer.poll(Duration.ofMillis(500)).asScala.filter(_.offset() >= offset).toList.map(_.value())
```

Till this I am able to get List of values. But I want to match key first using _.key()(key is available similar as value) if key matches my incoming key then I want to return the value. How can I do that?

Comment: `.filter(_.key() == IncomintKey)` ?

Answer (score 0):

I'm new to Scala too but I think you need to introduce and implicit decoder function and use it to get the Key from the ConsumerRecord.

```
records.iterator().asScala.toList.map(decoder(_))
```

Check this link out:
https://www.programcreek.com/scala/org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.KafkaConsumer